# css list li dot one color, text another color (CSS only)

Tags: css, list, colors, html-lists

I have list:

### HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>

<ol>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
</ol>
```

### CSS:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: black;
}
ol li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: black;
}
```

Example:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/T4NVj/)

### Question:

How to change `disc/decimal`(dots/numbers) in li to **red** color, but `text` will have **black** color?

### can't modify html !

For better imagination what I want to achieve:

[image: goal]

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: style the list red and then wrap your text in a span and style that black http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/T4NVj/1/

Comment: @Pete **can't modify html**, if I can, I won't be asking :)

Comment: sorry, didn't see that bit. You will need to use an image then as in sayem's answer

Comment: @Pete but, how can I add images for OL ? there are numbers :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out with `::pseudoElement` tag

### Solution:

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: red;
}
ol li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: red;
}
ol li:first-line, ul li:first-line  {
    color: black;
}
```

Example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/T4NVj/12/)

Comment: Obviously, this solution works only if the text for each bullet does not wrap one more than one line.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, how about something like this? It uses the before pseudo-element and declaring the bullet with unicode.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T4NVj/11/

```
ul li {
    margin-left: 2em;
    color: black;
    list-style:none;
}


ul li:before { 
    content: '\2022';
    color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 5;
    width: 5;
    left: -0.7em;
    top: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: **can't modify html**, if I can, I won't be asking :)

Comment: Oops. I missed that. I think you can do it with the :before pseudo element.

Comment: therefor this will apply to `OL` lists too ?

Comment: I fixed that. You're right, it shouldn't apply to ordered lists.

Comment: how can I use this for ordered lists ?

Comment: Do you want colored bullets for ol elements too or colored numbers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36082/discussion-between-meub-and-ing-michal-hudak)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the html, then your only option is to use an image -

```
ul li { 
    list-style-image: url(path_for_red_color_image.jpg);
}
```

Comment: looking for more complex solution, I can't add numbers as images in `OL` list

Answer (score 0):

CSS has grown up quite a bit since this question was asked back 2013.  Doing this change in CSS3 has become trivial.

```
body {
  /* Set "section" to 0 */
  counter-reset: section;
}
ul, ol {
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
}
ol li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section)  ". ";
  color: red;
}
ul li::before {
    content: "•";
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1em;
}
```

You can see an example here:
https://codepen.io/BIGREDBOOTS/pen/mdPpXRe